# Locked out of facebook app?

Tags: facebook

So, I no longer have access to save changes to my facebook app as its tied to the dynamic IP of the workstation I was using when I set it up & the other IP is that of the server making the call, but that server is headless.

Is there any way to get back control of the app?

Comment: WHat exactly do you mean with "save changes"? Can you access the app's settings under https://developers.facebook.com/apps

Comment: yes I can access it there, but when I try and update the IP to the new server I'm moving to (under advanced settings) I can't clicks save changes in the bottom right, its greyed out

Comment: Check whether the App Domain is given, and has the old value. If so, update appropriately

Comment: Thanks, I got desperate so I install gnome on the old headless server and made the changes from that server itself.